# Normal distribution tail probability inequality

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution

I am trying to show that $$P(X>t)\leq \frac{1}{2}e^\frac{-t^2}{2}$$ for $t>0$ where $X$ is a standard normal random variable.  Perhaps this is simple.  I have been starting with

$$ \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^\frac{-x^2}{2}dx \leq \int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{x}{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^2}{2}dx = \frac{1}{t\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-t^2}{2}$$

but this is not what I want...I am looking for a much stronger inequality.   Any help in the direction of getting the $1/2$?

Comment: so your approach is valid for $t\geq \sqrt{\pi/2}$. i do not know how to do it, so maybe, you start by assuming otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For every $t\gt0$, $$P(X\gt t)=\int_0^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-(x+t)^2/2}\mathrm dx,$$ and, for every $x\geqslant0$, $$\mathrm e^{-(x+t)^2/2}\leqslant\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm e^{-x^2/2},$$ hence $$P(X\gt t)\leqslant\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\int_0^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx=\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\,P(X\gt0).$$

Comment: nice and easy...

Comment: why $(x+t)^2$ ? shouldn't be $(x-t)^2$ ?